# Label puts spaces between buttons tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a calculator in Tkinter and I Finished the buttons, Then tried making a label on top of the buttons but this happened [problem's photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfJYj.png) as you can see it put spaces between buttons.
How can I fix that?

this is how I put the label :
`area1 = tk.Label(window, borderwidth=0, image=pixel, compound="c", font = myFont, width = 100, height = 177 ).grid(row = 1, column = 1)`

Update: Tried putting column = 0 but it didn't work

solution: I tried typing columnspan instead of column and increased its value every time I increased the width of the label and it worked

Comment: column=0, try again and let me know.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work.

Comment: what happend there?

Comment: the same problem

Comment: what about columnspan=2? Is there something else in the area of the label?

Comment: I tried columnspan = 2 and it did work! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at this logically: you have four columns along the bottom, and you want a single column at the top, right? The term for that is *spanning* - you want something in column zero to actually span four columns.

`grid` supports that with the `columnspan` option:

```
the_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky="nsew")
```

Comment: How could he have 4 columns when the Label is already the size of 3 Buttons? Don't know what he's downing over there.

Comment: @Atlas435: I don't understand your question. Looking at the screenshot there are clearly four columns. For example, one column has "1", the next has "2", the next has "3", and the next has "X".

Comment: I mean, in the code he shared there is no columnspan at all. How could the label become the size of 3 columns? But maybe I adress the question to the wrong developer.

Comment: @Atlas435: _" in the code he shared there is no columnspan at all. "_ - correct, and that's the problem. _"How could the label become the size of 3 columns?"_ - that's how geometry managers work - they have the ability to stretch or shrink widgets to fit the space allocated to them. Though, the point in this question is to have it span 4 columns, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

For a better solution i think you should use 'sticky' in your grid geometry. Sticky can help you stick a side of your button to the edge of the column u chose. it has the values n, s, w, e, which implies to north, south, west, east. you can add also more than one value together such as 'ne', 'nswe', etc. It all depends on your use. You can try in your case:

```
area1 = tk.Label(window, borderwidth=0, image=pixel, compound="c", font = myFont, width = 100, height = 177 )
area1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky='w')
```